# Error Displaying JqueryUI Modal Window From Within a Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this but thus far it's eluding me.  I'm attempting to open a modal window using jqueryui from within a function and it fails with the message "dialog is not a function".  Eventually I'm going to fill the modal with content pulled via ajax, but I've stripped it down to the bare bits to figure out why I can't instantiate the modal window.  I'm using jquery 1.7.2 and jqueryui 1.8.18 from the google CDN.

```
<!-- as a link -->
<a href="javascript:view_log('1');">Log 1</a>

<!-- as a button -->
<input type="button" id="thebutton" value="View Log" />

<script type="text/javascript">

/* this works on page load */
var test1 = $(document.createElement('div'));
test1.dialog({ modal:true });
test1.html('Testing');

/* this also works (on page load) */
function displayModal(content) {
    var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
    newDiv.dialog({ modal:true });
    newDiv.html(content);
}
displayModal('Testing by calling displayModal() function');

/* this fails with error "newDiv.dialog is not a function" */
function view_log(id) {
    displayModal('Log for id ' + id);
}

/* this also fails, same error ... */
$('#thebutton').bind('click', function() {
    displayModal('Testing again...');
});

</script>
```

Any jquery experts that can point out my error?

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/FFrYz/

Comment: @Cameron Martin The link one does not work in your fiddle.

Comment: I should add that I've been testing in FF with Firebug, haven't even looked at IE yet ...

Comment: I created my jsfiddle demo in Firefox too

Comment: Interestingly, I just tried it in chrome and both link and button worked fine.  This is one of those rare cases where something doesn't work in FF.

Comment: That possibly has something to do with named function scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine for me. The only thing I can think of is you should use `$(document).ready(function() {});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thebutton').bind('click', function() {
        displayModal('Testing again...');
    });
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9rEcQ/2/)

Comment: Funny, I tried that as well, thinking maybe the page had not fully loaded, but I still get the error.

Comment: Did you try the demo. It is your code just pasted into fiddle and it is working for me. Is there anything else on your page that could be interfering?

Comment: Thanks Josh, there must be something else in my page that causing the error, I'll have to dig in deeper.  Good to know I wasn't completely losing my marbles (only partially).